How to copy all files with specific extension and rename them adding the subdirectory names
I have a folder Bash with two subdirectories Origin and Destination.
Origin has subdirectories 1, 2, 3, 4.
Each of them has its own subdirectories. For example, 1 has subdirectories 11, 12, 13 ,etc. 2 has subdirectories 21, 22, 23, etc.
The directory 11 has files 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt and files with other extension.
The directory 12 has different .txt files but with the same names 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt and files with other extension as well.
In fact, every final subdirectory (e.g. 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, ...) has text files with the same name.

How do I copy all text files from Origin to Destination, but because all file names are the same, with changing the names, including the subdirectories name where they come from?
For example, 1.txt from 11 subdirectory will have a name 1_11_1.txt in Destination and 1.txt from 23 subdirectory will have 2_23_1.txt name.

How do I create .csv file in the Destination with all the original file names, their original location and their new file names?


Could you please explain the process of your thinking, how you create such bash script?
Thank you!

find Origin -name "*.txt" -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' origin_name
do
  name="${origin_name#*/}"
  destination_name="Destination/${name//\//_}"
  echo '"'"$origin_name"'","'"$destination_name"'"'
  # cp "$origin_name" "$destination_name"
done


Find all *.txt files inside the Origin directory, separate with NUL instead of spaces just in case the file names have spaces in them
Pipe the result into the loop, reading record by record, making sure to cut records by the NUL byte
name is after the first slash
destination_name has Destination prepended, and all slashes in name changed to underscores
print out the CSV row
copy the file

EDIT: Got beaten by a hair, but still I think there's value

More robust version! Note in order to perform statistics and overall result on whole loop, I prefer to use inline command and invert the fork: while IFS= read -d '' ...done < <(find .. -print0)

@Amadan Could you please explain a bit more in your code? Where is CSV file created?And could you please explain the syntax of destination_name="Destination/${name////_}" ?

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub could you please explain the logic of your command and the previous command, and why your version is more robust? Thank you!

CSV is printed to the standard output by the echo command. You can redirect the output to save it to a file. ${var//search/replacement} is substituted with the value of var variable, modified by replacing all instances of search with the string replacement; in this case, all instances of / (which has to be escaped, so it is written as \/) with _. Also, to actually perform the copy, uncomment the cp line by removing #. F.Hauri was saying my version is more robust than another answer, by using NUL as terminators; not doing that makes the code break if filenames contain spaces

@Amadan what if one of directories has a lot of nested subdirectories with the strange names which I want to omit? It seems to me that your code recursively will add all the subdirectories names from the path. What should I do if I want to skip' let's say the subdirectory with the specific name? Or the forth level subdirectory?

You did not mention anything about ignoring dirs. You can do a lot with find. For example, to skip directory with a specific name, find Origin -name BADDIR -prune -o -name "*.txt" -print (to experiment with; replace -print with -print0 when you use it in the script). Or use -path instead of -name to specify the exact path, not a name that can be found anywhere. To skip level 4, I believe you would have to combine two find expressions, as you cannot combine global options using "or": (find Origin -mindepth 4 -name "*.txt" -print; find Origin -maxdepth 2 -name "*.txt" -print).

@Amadan is 'echo '"'"$origin_name"'","'"$destination_name"'"'' is the line for creating csv basically? Could you please clarify what these additional '"' at the beginning mean? It doesn't include the original path and destination path, only names.

$var expands to the value of the variable, but there are cases where the shell will do something you don't want (e.g. if the variable has multiple consecutive spaces). Thus, to make shell not do that, you need to surround it by double quotes: "$var". However, in order for CSV to be well-formed in most situations you would also want double quotes in CSV; to make shell print a double quote, surround it with single quotes: '"'. The output should include the relative path from current directory; you can insert $PWD/ before the variables to prepend the current directory.

You're looking for something like this:
find Origin -type f -exec bash -c '
for src; do
  ext=${src#"${src%.*}"}
  dst=${src%"$ext"}
  dst=${dst#Origin/}
  dst=Destination/${dst//\//_}$ext
  echo cp "$src" "$dst"
done' sh {} +

Remove echo if the output looks good.

Another |sh version, using sed ( handling double-quotes ;-): find Origin -type f -name '*.txt' -print| sed 's/"/\\"/g;h;s/^Origin/Destination/;s+/+_+g;s+_+/+;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/cp "\2" "\1"/' ... |sh.

Could you please explain what is going on in your code a little bit more? When I just run it in my terminal nothing happens: there is an output in the terminal window but no files are being copied.

Also, from what I understood from this code - it's not choosing only txt files, right? it copies all the files of any extension, but I need only .txt.

Another question is I about the code: do I understand correctly that find Origin -type f -exec bash -c  finds the path to the file which automatically assigns to src variable?

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub could you please explain why nothing is going on after I run the commands above?

find Origin -type f -name '*.txt' -print| sed 's/"/\\"/g;h;s/^Origin/Destination/;s+/+_+g;s+_+/+;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/cp "\2" "\1"/' will prepare a list of command you have to | sh to execute (after verification): find Origin -type f -name '*.txt' -print| sed 's/"/\\"/g;h;s/^Origin/Destination/;s+/+_+g;s+_+/+;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/cp "\2" "\1"/' | sh

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub so, it prepares the list of commands but doesn't execute that? It does give me the list of commands, but how to actually execute them at the same time? Sorry, I am not familiar with bash at all

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub  how to write csv file as well with the all metadata: original name, final name and the path?

based on sed script, there is not a lot of change to transform your list of command into csv file... So you coud use tee as in Pipe output to two different commands: find ... -print| tee >(sed ...) >(sed ...) >/dev/null.

Try: find Origin -type f -name '*.txt' -print| tee >(sed -e 's/"/\\"/g;h;s/^Origin/Destination/;s+/+_+g;s+_+/+;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/"\2","\1"/' -e '1iOrigin,Destination' >Destination/transfet.csv) | sed 's/"/\\"/g;h;s/^Origin/Destination/;s+/+_+g;s+_+/+;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/cp "\2" "\1"/' | sh

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

| is a pipe,to pass output of first command as input to second command. Please read some documentation https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html and yes, seeing command line in terminal, then repeat command and add | sh will pass output of whole line as input to sh then execute lines.

Step-by-Step Thought Process

Directory Traversal: We need to use a command like find or a loop to
walk through all the subdirectories and find .txt files.

Extract Subdirectory Names: Using basename or string manipulation, we
can extract the parent subdirectory names.

Renaming and Copying Files: Use the extracted names to construct a
new name for each .txt file before copying it to the destination.

Recording the CSV Information: As we process each file, we append its
original location and new name to a .csv file in the destination
folder.
#!/bin/bash
Set paths for origin and destination
ORIGIN_DIR="./Bash/Origin"
DEST_DIR="./Bash/Destination"
CSV_FILE="$DEST_DIR/files_info.csv"
Create destination directory if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$DEST_DIR"
Initialize CSV file with header
echo "Original Path,New Path" > "$CSV_FILE"
Traverse through the origin directory and find all .txt files
find "$ORIGIN_DIR" -type f -name "*.txt" | while read file; do
Get the base file name (e.g., 1.txt)
filename=$(basename "$file")
Get the subdirectories (e.g., from Bash/Origin/1/11/1.txt extract 1/11)
subdir_path=$(dirname "${file#$ORIGIN_DIR/}")
Extract the first two levels of subdirectories (e.g., 1/11)
level1=$(echo "$subdir_path" | cut -d'/' -f1)
level2=$(echo "$subdir_path" | cut -d'/' -f2)
Create new file name (e.g., 1_11_1.txt)
new_filename="${level1}${level2}${filename}"
Copy the file to the destination with the new name
cp "$file" "$DEST_DIR/$new_filename"
Add the original and new paths to the CSV file
echo "$file,$DEST_DIR/$new_filename" >> "$CSV_FILE"
done
echo "File transfer and renaming complete. CSV file generated at CSV_FILE"



Could you please clarify for me the syntax of the extracting of the levels of subdirectories? When I try to run this code, it says line 21: syntax error: unexpected end of file. Any ideas on that?
